# How to delete a Sagemaker Ground Truth Labeling Job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

How can I delete an `Amazon Sagemaker Ground Truth Labeling Job`?

Can't find that option on the console.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to delete a Labeling Job.

I've also had a similar issue and was wondering if there was a way to do it through the console, SDK or CLI. I spoke to a cloud support engineer and this is in his own words:

```
At the moment it is not possible to delete a Labeling Job from
console, CLI or SDK. If the Job is "In Progress" you can stop the job
to avoid further labeling and charges associated with it.
```

If you are concerned about charges, the engineer did assure me that failed and completed jobs will not be charged.

You will only charged for the following:

- 1- Worker charges if you are using Public or Vendor workforce.
- 2- S3 storage charges for the input and output data
- 3- Fixed price per labeled object. https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/groundtruth/pricing/